# How to convert strings to a 'mm/dd/yyyy' format in Teradata?

Tags: datetime, teradata

In my DB I have string like 10192013 (mmddyyyy) and 152015 (mmddyyyy) . I want the to be converted to date/time format 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

How would I achieve that ?

I tried CAST ( --date strings-- AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') but that did not work out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cast numerics to string and then cast to a date, simply calculate based on the internal date format:

```
CAST((cnst_birth_yr_num - 1900) * 10000 
     + cnst_birth_mth_num * 100
     + cnst_birth_dy_num AS DATE)
```

This results in a DATE, the string representation is usually done in the client, otherwise utilize TO_DATE plus a format:

```
TO_CHAR(CAST((cnst_birth_yr_num - 1900) * 10000 
             + cnst_birth_mth_num * 100
             + cnst_birth_dy_num AS DATE),  'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: That helped . But If I try 
SELECT TOP 100 TO_CHAR(CAST((cnst_birth_yr_num) 
             + cnst_birth_mth_num
             + cnst_birth_dy_num AS DATE),  'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM arc_mdm_tbls.cnst_birth

that says invalid date supplied. Why is it so ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: Your query doesn't do the needed calculation. If my query fails it indicates bad data, you can use `(cnst_birth_mth_num (FORMAT '99/')) ||
(cnst_birth_dy_num  (FORMAT '99/')) ||
(cnst_birth_yr_num  (FORMAT '9999'))` to get a string without checking for a correct date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Teradata SQL assistant, then maybe you're stuck with one format. You can change it by going into `Tools>Options>Data Format`.
 If you're using BTEQ, then maybe `CAST` function should work.

Answer (score 0):

Though Dnoeth approach is best..but give this one a try...

```
select 
case when length(test)=8
 then
    cast((cast(substr(test,5)||'-'||substr(test,1,2)||'-'||substr(test,3,2)  as varchar(10)) )
    as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    when length(test )=6
    then
    cast(substr(test,3)||'-'||'0'||substr(test ,1,1)||'-0'||substr(test,2,1) as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
end as dateformat
from test1;
```